# How does impulse lose energy in rotation?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, energy-conservation, signal-processing

I have this kind of empirical signal in Electronics where the signal is 1D current measurement (AD current coming from dynamic processes) such that the wire rotates in a big volume of water/mud:

[image]

where is a sinusoidal module cancellation unit such as described [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11143342). 
I do not understand what can cause such periodic thinning in the signal. 
I think the possible causes are

- rotation of wire in the container; so accelerating and losing energy
- possible thinning of the wire itself

How can you the thinning of the signal be formed?

Comment: *"I have this kind of empirical signal in Electronics"*...I am completely at a lows what that is supposed to tell us. *What* signal is this, i.e. what are the axes? What are you measuring? What is the setup? This is completely unanswerable without more context.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I added the description about the signal.

Comment: So, "the signal"...what is the signal source? With what are you receiving it? Is there a sinusoidal source that transmits a AC current through the wires? Something else?

Comment: @ACuriousMind It is AD current coming from dynamic processes. There is a common sinusoidal source cancellation module in the system so it should not be causing it.